# Does OSX Mavericks prevent third party software from having a "Save as" option?

Tags: macos, adobe-photoshop

I'm considering upgrading some of my machines from Snow Leopard to OSX Mavericks (and possibly buying a new Mac Pro), but I'm extremely concerned about losing the "Save as" option in third party software such as Photoshop, After Effects, Avid etc. My question to anyone running Mavericks is this: Have you come across any piece of software that still has a "Save as" option? (If anyone has had experience with an Adobe product running on Mavericks that would be even better).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this question is complicated.  Way back in Lion, Apple began to offer optional API's to software developers that would make it easier for applications to manipulate different versions of saved documents.  The most noticable repurcussion of these updated APIs was the replacement of the `Save As..` menu item by `Duplicate` and `Rename...` menu items.  For those interested in the details, the best guide is the [relevant section of John Siracusa's masterful Lion review](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2011/07/mac-os-x-10-7/7/).  However, use of these new APIs was optional, and *the old functionality is still supported in Lion, Mountain Lion, and Mavericks*.

Most non-Apple software still uses the old `Save As` menu for now, but in Mavericks some of the Apple applications have migrated to the new `Duplicate` menu.  As far as I know, Apple has not announced any plans to make the `Duplicate` model mandatory in the future, so this inconsistency is likely to stick around for a while.

**Bottom line: In Mavericks, most applications still have the `Save As...` menu item.**

Photoshop in Mavericks, using the familiar `Save As...` menu item:

[image: Photoshop]

Textedit in Mavericks, using the new `Duplicate` menu item:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the great answer @BringMyCakeBack! I read the review you linked to and came to the realization that I was suffering from a prime example of what the author described as "geek panic". It does seem that Apple implemented a pretty elegant method of version control with Lion/Mountain Lion and Mavericks. Do you know if that auto save feature is active in Photoshop? In any case, thanks again!

Comment: I'm still using CS4, which doesn't have any autosave, even on Mavericks.  I've read that Adobe implemented its own autosave feature in CS6: http://www.photoshopessentials.com/basics/background-auto-save-cs6/  
  However, this is different than the new `Duplicate` functionality that the Ars Technica review was talking about.

Comment: The Persistant 'autosave' feature is not for fully integrated 'heavy' suites like Adobe, and shouldn't be looked at like that.

It's for small developers to have simple, effective and intuitive means of providing an autosave functionality. It doesn't support versioning or anything of that level.

Answer (score 0):

Third-party applications don't lose their "Save as..." option.  I use Photoshop and Illustrator CS5, and both still have "Save as".  So do the apps in Office:Mac 2011.  I did a quick glance at my apps and couldn't find any app that *did* have "Save as..." before Mavericks that didn't have it after I upgraded.

Comment: Fantastic! Looks like I'll be upgrading some of my computers this weekend. Thanks so much @nadyne!

Comment: Don't forget to backup before you upgrade! :)

Comment: I have everything backed up on a mirrored raid, so I think I'm good. :) Did you have any issues with information loss when you upgraded to Mavericks?

Comment: I didn't have any issues, I just always believe in making sure that I've got a good backup when I upgrade.  The time when you most need a backup is when you don't have one!